# office 365 file Get drive properties returning false

Tags: php, rest, office365

I am trying to get the onedrive drive properties using the office 365 REST API but i am getting the response as false when i var_dump my response. Below is my code.

```
$file_api = "https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/drive/files"; 
             $headers = array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: Bearer'.$token, // Always need our auth token!
            );
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file_api);            
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);           
            curl_close($ch);
            var_dump($result);
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here ?

I am referencing this link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations#DriveoperationsGetdriveproperties

Respone is

```
array (
  'url' => 'https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/drive/files',
  'content_type' => NULL,
  'http_code' => 0,
  'header_size' => 0,
  'request_size' => 0,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 30.749314999999999,
  'namelookup_time' => 0.20429800000000001,
  'connect_time' => 0.20474100000000001,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0,
  'size_upload' => 0,
  'size_download' => 0,
  'speed_download' => 0,
  'speed_upload' => 0,
  'download_content_length' => -1,
  'upload_content_length' => -1,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0,
  'redirect_time' => 0,
  'redirect_url' => '',
  'primary_ip' => '104.146.150.43',
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'primary_port' => 443,
  'local_ip' => '192.168.8.46',
  'local_port' => 54470,
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace {tenant} in the url with your Office 365 tenant name.